# Change tabs on form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have created following tabs in my html file using bootstrap

```html
<li><a href="#section1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#section2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#section3" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#section4" data-toggle="tab">Section 4</a></li>
```

Each tab has a form. All the form data is submitted by AJAX. I want to switch tabs on form submit. For example when user submits form in section1 I want form to be submitted by ajax and then display the next form which is in section2.

I am using following script to submit form data

```js
$("#section1Form").submit(function(e) {

  var url = "storeDetails.php"; 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize(), 
    success: function(data){
       alert(data);
    }
  });

  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).trigger('reset');
});
```

Comment: Are you using JQuery UI tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add on the succes of the form
   `$('a[href="#section2"]').trigger('click');` as below

```
$("#section1Form").submit(function(e) {

var url = "storeDetails.php"; 
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: $(this).serialize(), 
success: function(data){
   alert(data);
 $('a[href="#section2"]').trigger('click');    }
});

e.preventDefault();
$(this).trigger('reset');
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This solution works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ajax` is asynchronous and will execute your "success" callback when it's done, you should simply be able to add your jquery after the alert statement:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize(), 
    success: function(data){
       alert(data);
       // put your jquery tab display logic here
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a[href="#section2"]').trigger('click');// after form submit as shown in example

$("#section1Form").submit(function(e) {

    var url = "storeDetails.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('a[href="#section2"]').trigger('click');
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).trigger('reset');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="section1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div id="section2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div id="section3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
</div>
```